# Generating friendly URLs / htaccess from database

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, friendly-url

**The scenario**

I have a menu builder (Title, Link...) in PHP/MySQL, which I want to be able to configure the friendly SEO rule in the .htaccess

**The issues**

Here is a typical rewrite rule at the moment:

```
RewriteRule ^computer/other-components/?(.*)$ index.php?CategoryID=9&SubCategoryID=2 [NC,L]
```

I could write all these manually in the .htaccess but there are a couple of issues:

1. I would have to manually do this each time I want to add/make changes to the page structure
2. It's really long.

I've read that writing directly to the .htaccess is a no-no for security, so what would be best to implement something like this? Wordpress and similar CMSs do similar, so what is recommended here?

Comment: Are you just wanting to create a simple router for your app? Why not look at building it in PHP?

Comment: Thanks Sam, what's an example of a simple router with PHP? I want to maintain friendly URLs, are you suggesting to have a single rule in the .htaccess to go to a PHP file to process the request?

Comment: Check out this [github repo](https://github.com/skipperbent/simple-php-router). Yes, as you mentioned `.htaccess` in any prod environment has to be carefully crafted; and defining paths in the `.htaccess` is prone to bugs.